# Bash: split on space but not on escaped space

Tags: bash, split, escaping, whitespace, filenames

I'm trying to write a bash script that read user's input (some files so user can use `TAB` completion) and copy them into a specific folder.

```
#/bin/bash
read -e files
for file in $files
do
    echo $file
    cp "$file" folder/"$file"
done
```

It's ok for: `file1 file2 ...`

Or with : `file*` (even if there is a filename with space in the folder).

But it's not working for filenames with space escaped with backslash `\`  like : `file\ with\ space` escaped spaces are ignored and string is split on each spaces, even escaped.

I saw information on quoting, printf, IFS, read and while... I think it's very basic bash script but I can't find a good solution. Can you help me?

Comment: Aside: The unix spelling is "directory", not "folder".

Comment: Why not just quote `$files` (eg. for file in "$files")?

Comment: @l'L'l, because that would disable globbing, which the OP explicitly wants.

Comment: @l'L'l, ...and doing it at the `for file in "$files"` point makes the loop useless -- it'll only iterate once, over the exact and entire content of `$files`; might as well not have a loop at all in that case.

Comment: @Lucien, ...btw, in any kind of more real-life scripting case, the preferred approach is to take input on the command line rather than prompting on stdin. If the user specifies a list of globs on the command line, they all get expanded there, so you can just expand `"$@"` to get the exact names and not deal with any of this mess. Easier to automate when calling from other scripts that way, as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Yes, that makes sense; would a `while` function work though (eg. while read -e file ; do cp "$file folder/$file" ; done)?

Comment: @lll, it'd need to be more like `cp $file folder/`, which is... well, what my answer is doing. You can't have `folder/$file` as an explicit destination because you can't have a glob on the destination end of a copy, and you can't quote the `$file` or it won't be glob-expanded (which is why I argue that naming it `file` is misleading, when what it stores is not a filename but a glob that's expected to expand to one or more filenames).

Comment: @lll, ...`cp "$file folder/$file"` is just passing `cp` one argument; since spec and implementation mandate one or more sources and exactly one destination, it requires a minimum of two.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: yep, somehow just realized that now. :)

Comment: Thank you for all your comments and sorry for my bad variable names, I have a poor knowledge in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearing `IFS` prior to your unquoted expansion will allow globbing to proceed while preventing string-splitting:

```
IFS=$' \t\n' read -e -a globs  # read glob expressions into an array
IFS=''
for glob in "${globs[@]}"; do  # these aren't filenames; don't claim that they are.
  files=( $glob )              # expand the glob into filenames

  # detect the case where no files matched by checking whether the first result exists
  # these *would* need to be quoted, but [[ ]] turns off string-splitting and globbing
  [[ -e $files || -L $files ]] || {
    printf 'ERROR: Glob expression %q did not match any files!\n' "$glob" >&2
    continue
  }

  printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"  # print one line per file matching
  cp -- "${files[@]}" folder/  # copy those files to the target
done
```

Note that we're enforcing the default `IFS=$' \t\n'` during the `read` operation, which ensures that unquoted whitespace is treated as a separator between array elements at that stage. Later, with `files=( $glob )`, by contrast, we have `IFS=''`, so whitespace no longer can break individual names apart.

Comment: Thank you for this answer it works exactly as I wanted and for the comments they help me to understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the filenames into an array, then loop over the array elements:

```
read -e -a files
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    echo "$file"
    cp "$file" folder/"$file"
done
```

Reading into a single string won't work no matter how you quote: the string will either be split up at each space (when unquoted) or not at all (when quoted). See [this canonical Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) for details (your case is the last item in the list).

This prevents globbing, i.e., `file*` is not expanded. For a solution that takes this into account, see [Charles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37426132/3266847).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But `file*` is not working anymore. It does not loop on all the files beginning with `file` just on the file named `file*`. I would like to allow this kind of input

Answer (score 1):

There is a fully functional solution for files and globs.

With the help of using xargs (which is able to preserve quoted strings). But you need to write files with spaces inside quotes:

```
"file with spaces"
```

When you use the script: Unquote the read and quote the assignment for `listOfFiles`.

I am also taking advantage of some ideas on the post of [@CharlesDuffy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) (thanks Charles).

```
#!/bin/bash

# read -e listOfFiles
listOfFiles='file1 file* "file with spaces"'

IFS=''
while IFS='' read glob; do     # read each file expressions into an array
  files=( $glob )              # try to expand the glob into filenames

  # If no file match the split glob
  # Then assume that the glob is a file and test its existence
  [[ -e $files || -L $files ]] || {
      files="$glob"
      [[ -e $files || -L $files ]] || {
          printf 'ERROR: Glob "%q" did not match any file!\n' "$glob" >&2
          continue
      }
  }

  printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"  # print one line per file matching
  cp -- "${files[@]}" folder/  # copy those files to the target
done < <(xargs -n1 <<<"$listOfFiles")
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the extra code accomplishes anything when the shell is at default settings -- a glob that doesn't match evaluates to itself, absent `nullglob` being active. Can you provide an example case where this fixes a bug present in the preceding answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Because of the last line: `xargs -n1 <<<"$listOfFiles"` the part inside double quotes `"file with spaces"` appear as one line to the shell (not broken into parts by the spaces). Once that is a single line, we can test if a line is a glob, or in failing, if it is a file, which `"file with spaces"` successfully is (if it exist). Your answer does not allow nor process the case in which there is a `"file with spaces"` in the given list (which is written in code in the script here). I hope that I was able to explain the difference. Not a bug: I hope that it is an improvement.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Yup, I only support `file\ with\ spaces`, so this is indeed an improvement.

Comment: ...the place where I got held up, by the way, was trying to figure out in what scenario `files="$glob"` will result in a match, when `files=( $glob )` didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the answers of both Charles Duffy and user2350426 do not preserve escaped `*`s; they will expand them, too.

Benjamin's approach, however, won't do globbing at all. He is mistaken in that you can first put your globs in a string and then load them into an array.

Then it will work as desired:

```
globs='file1 file\ 2 file-* file\* file\"\"'  # or read -re here 

# Do splitting and globbing:
shopt -s nullglob
eval "files=( $globs )"
shopt -u nullglob

# Now we can use ${files[@]}:
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    printf "%s\n" "$file"
done
```

Also note the use of `nullglob` to ignore non-expandable globs.
You may also want to use `failglob` or, for more fine-grained control, code like in the aforementioned answers.

Inside functions, you probably want to `declare` variables, so they stay local.